# Is it possible to delete record without using forms in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to delete a record but I haven't been successful, apparently my code is wrong. Solutions i came across say i have to use a post in my form method and add the method_field helper. This would mean my view having a form in it, i want to avoid this if possible. Is it then possible to do my delete another way. Below is my code

snippet of my view

```
<div class="backbtn">
<a class="btn btn-savvy-delete" href="/tasks/{{$task->id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"> Delete</i></a>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
<p><strong>Owner:</strong> {{ ucfirst($task->employee->firstname) }} {{" "}}    {{ ucfirst($task->employee->lastname) }}</p>

<p><strong>Task:</strong> {{ $task->title }}</p>

<p><strong>Description:</strong> {{ $task->description }}</p>
</div>
```

TaskController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Task::destroy($id);

    Session::flash('status', "Task was successfully deleted.");

    return redirect('/tasks');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::delete('/tasks/{id}', 'TaskController@delete');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what error you are getting, but i can point out a few things. For one use `Route::get` instead of `::delete`, you are calling it via a link not a form method.

Secondly to delete follow what the laravel doc says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#deleting-models) eg.

```
$task = App\Task::find(1);

$task->delete();
```

Comment: I already had **Route::get('/tasks/{id}', 'TaskController@show')** so i used **Route::get('/tasks/{id}/delete', 'TaskController@destroy')** and that fixed it. Is this a good practice?

Comment: yes as far as i know it is. You shouldn't encounter any issues with that